# Making a function work with generic type T instead of char*

Tags: c++

So im trying to convert my prehash function from using a char* to using a genericc type T. Here is the function:

```
unsigned long prehash(unsigned char *str) {
    unsigned long h = 5381;
    int c;
    while (c = *str++) { 
        h = ((h << 5) + h) + c;
    }
    return h;
}
```

My first thought was to just change the `char*` to just `T`:

```
unsigned long prehash(T str) {
    T h = 5381;
    T c;
    while (c = str++) { 
        h = ((h << 5) + h) + c;
    }
    return h;
}
```

But it hasnt worked. I know im missing a step here but I thought generic types could be anything? Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `But it hasnt works.` Please edit question and describe 1-what you expect 2- what happens. Build error? Runtime? Or maybe you just forgot `template<typename T>`? What error message?

Comment: `T` can't be `unsigned char *`, `unsigned long` and `int` at the same time.

Comment: `T` is just a name that is commonly used for template parameters, it is not a "generic type", in your code it is just a type that lacks a declaration

Comment: Looks like you want to pass a string as argument. But the ++ operator does not make much sense for a string. When using char* it makes sense to increment the pointer

Comment: You cannot write a hash function template that is good for every type. Each type needs to implement its own hash function.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. well im really just generating a unique number for the string. But Im trying to do that for whatever 'T' may be.

Comment: "Im trying to do that for whatever 'T' may be". You can't.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.ok thanks

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
template<typename T>
unsigned long prehash(const T &value) {
    const unsigned char *pvalue = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&value);
    unsigned long h = 5381;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(value); ++i) {
        int c = *pvalue++;
        h = ((h << 5) + h) + c;
    }
    return h;
}

template<>
unsigned long prehash(const unsigned char *str) {
    unsigned long h = 5381;
    int c;
    while (c = *str++) { 
        h = ((h << 5) + h) + c;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 fixed